# Problem grasping this probability problem

Tags: probability

Let a urn containing $ r $ red balls, $ b $ white balls, we perform n draws with replacement of red, and without replacement of white, we introduce the event $ B_k $ : the $k$-th ball is white, calculate the probability $p$ of drawing exactly one white ball throughout the $n$ draws
My idea :
so we want this type of outcome $\overline{B_1}...\overline{B_{i-1}}B_i\overline{B_{i+1}}...\overline{B_n}$
i have a problem with whether the draws being independent or not also i dont understand how does with/without replacement will affect the calculations
**EDIT**
$P(B_k) = (\frac{r}{b+r})^{k-1} \cdot \frac{b}{b+r} \cdot (\frac{r}{b+r-1})^{n-k}$
and to finish this problem and $p = \sum_{k=1}^n P(B_k)$ is this valid?

Comment: What is your problem with this problem?

Comment: @GrahamKemp can you tell me how to approach it?

Comment: Hint: What is the probability for drawing a red ball when given that all previous draws were red?  What is the probability for drawing a white ball when given that all previous draws were red?  What is the probability for drawing a red ball when given that exactly one among all previous draws was white?

Comment: Note: When all previous balls where red, the red ball was always replaced.  When exactly one previous ball was white, there will be one less white ball in the current draw.

Comment: the probability of drawing a red ball at the i-th draw such that all the previous draws are red too is : $P_{B_1 ^c \cap ....\cap B_{i-1}^c} (B_i^c) = \frac{\binom{r-(i-1)} {1}}{\binom{n-(i-1)}{1}}$ @GrahamKemp

Comment: @GrahamKemp when we have an experience happening with replacement we used the binomial law, and without replacement we use the hypergeometric law right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149395/discussion-between-mohamed-salhi-and-graham-kemp).

Comment: Think again.  When all previous draws were red, there will still be $r$ red balls due to the replacements.    You also begin with $b+r$ balls;  $n$ has nothing to do with the count of *balls*.

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI: Have you got the answer ?

Comment: yes but not sure of its validity @trueblueanil , so $P(B_k) = (\frac{r}{b+r})^{k-1} \cdot \frac{b}{b+r} \cdot (\frac{r}{b+r-1})^{n-k}$ is this valid?

Comment: Yes, it is alright.

Comment: can you tell me why the last term of the right has an exponent of $n-k$ instead of $n-1$ because Graham wrote the latter ? @trueblueanil

Comment: Because $(k-1) + 1 + (n-k) = n$ draws

Comment: can you tell me how can i evaluate that sum @trueblueanil

Comment: Rearrange it until you have a function of $r,b,n$, multiplied by geometric series.

Comment: thank you so much ! @GrahamKemp